# DNN deprecated methods on upgrade

Tags: upgrade, dotnetnuke

I'm trying to upgrade my old DNN website to DNN version 9.8.0. The problem is that I have one custom module installed and it is using deprecated methods that I'm resolving using the table of deprecated methods and I ran on one issue that I don't really understand what to do with it:

**retRole = DotNetNuke.Security.Roles.RoleProvider.Instance().GetRole(module.PortalId, roleid);**

Error is:  'DotNetNuke.Security.Roles.RoleProvider' does not contain a definition for 'GetRole' and no extension method 'GetRole' accepting a first argument of type 'DotNetNuke.Security.Roles.RoleProvider' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

In the table of deprecated method, for **public virtual RoleInfo GetRole(int portalId, int roleId)** it says: ***Deprecated in DotNetNuke 6.2. Roles are cached in the business layer***

Does anyone knows what it means and how to resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the RoleProvider, I would use the RoleController:
**retRole = DotNetNuke.Security.Roles.RoleController.Instance().GetRoleById(module.PortalId, roleid);**
In DNN9.8, RoleProvider doesn't have the method GetRole anymore.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It works, but I just had to remove () from Instance(). So the solution was: retRole = DotNetNuke.Security.Roles.RoleController.Instance.GetRoleById(module.PortalId, roleid);